# How to align tabular to the top of the side-by-side minipage?

Tags: vertical-alignment

How do I align the table with contact info to the top of the page? My best try is this:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,booktabs,cmap,hyperref,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

%{\bfseries\LARGE Egor Tensin}\\
%\begin{flushright}
%\end{flushright}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
{\bfseries\LARGE John Smith}\\
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\itshape}rl}
\toprule
Email:& \href{mailto:John.Smith@gmail.com}{\ttfamily John.Smith@gmail.com} \\
\midrule
Tel.:& +0\,(000)\,00-00-000 \\
\midrule
Address:& 221B Baker Street \\
& London, England \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\
\blindtext[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and see how the `tabular` is aligned to the bottom of the "John Smith" line? How do I align it to the top of the `minipage`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boxes are aligned on their top items, but that is text in one case and the rule in the other.  `array` package (which you are implictly loading) defines `\firsthline` for exactly this case so you could go

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\itshape}rl}
%\toprule
\firsthline
```

But if you want to stick with the heavier booktabs toprule then you can space up by the
amount of space that takes:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\heavyrulewidth+\abovetopsep\relax}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\itshape}rl}
\toprule
%\firsthline
```

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm! Thank you very much.

Comment: What to use if I have a `\cline{0-1}` instead of a `\hline`?

Comment: @masu you can use `\vspace` as shown for `\toprule`

Comment: oh, sorry, I've been unobservant.

Answer (score 0):

A quick go-through the "Related Questions" section gave me this quick & dirty solution: adding `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning of `minipage`s does the trick, though adding some vertical space and not being elegant nor idiomatic. David's answer is much better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` instead of `{tabular}`, you will have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,booktabs,cmap,hyperref,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
{\bfseries\LARGE John Smith}\\
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{NiceTabular}[t]{>{\itshape}rl}
\toprule
Email:& \href{mailto:John.Smith@gmail.com}{\ttfamily John.Smith@gmail.com} \\
\midrule
Tel.:& +0\,(000)\,00-00-000 \\
\midrule
Address:& 221B Baker Street \\
& London, England \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}\\
\blindtext[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]