# Top alignment of listings in a tabu/tabularx-environment - lstlisting/minted in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minted, lstlisting

I want to insert code snippets into a tabular environment. For the Code snippets I'm using the package listing and to insert it into a tabular environment I put the code into a box. To get linebreaks within my code I put all this in a minipage-environment. The **top alignment** (which is mandatory) of the cells with the code does not work properly anymore. I guess the problem is that I have to use something like an lrbox to insert the code into a tabular environment.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? A general approach would be preferrable, because I want to use this regularly.

[image: lstlisting-minipage-missaligned]

*edit:* After some research I added a partial answer, but I still would appreciate some help with top-aligning.

```
\documentclass[%
    twoside=false,%
    paper=a4,%
    DIV=15,%)
    BCOR=0mm,%
    parskip=false,%
    fontsize=10pt,%
    ]{scrreprt}%
%%% TABLES
\usepackage{array}%
\usepackage{tabu}%
%\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%%% COLORS
\usepackage{color}% colors!
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{graybg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}%
%%% CODE HIGHLIGHTING
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}%
\lstset{        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
                breaklines=true,
                columns=[c]fixed,
                backgroundcolor=\color{graybg},
                numbersep=2pt,
                xleftmargin=0mm,
                xrightmargin=0mm,
                breakautoindent=false,
                autogobble=true
                }%
%
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}%
%%%
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
 \begin{lstlisting}
   int main() {
   printf("hello, world");
   return 0;
   }
 \end{lstlisting}
 \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
%
{\tabulinesep=1.2mm%
\begin{table}[h!]%
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l,p]X[l,p]X[l,p]}%
\toprule%
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{Some code} & \textbf{Output}\tabularnewline%
\midrule%
some blabla & printf() & printf()\tabularnewline%   
hello world & \usebox\mybox & hello, world\tabularnewline%
\bottomrule%
\end{tabu}%
\end{table}%
}
%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the package [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) I am at least able to create code snippets inside the standard `tabular` environment, thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112994/how-to-embed-a-minted-environment-inside-a-tabular-environment#113044) link.
Additionally [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188003/minted-environment-inside-tabular/188163#188163) answer removes the extra vertical space successfully for top alignment (and calls this environment `tabminted`).
[image: tabminted-aligned-nobackgroundcoloring]

```
\documentclass[%
    twoside=false,%
    paper=a4,%
    DIV=15,%)
    BCOR=0mm,%
    parskip=false,%
    fontsize=10pt,%
    ]{scrreprt}%
%%% TABLES
%\usepackage{array}%
%\usepackage{tabu}%
%\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%%% COLORS
\usepackage{color}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{graybg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
%%% CODE HIGHLIGHTING
\usepackage[
    cache=false% cache=false longer compiling, but no cache errors
    ]{minted}
\setminted[c]{%
    autogobble=true,%
    breakanywhere=true,%
    breaklines=true,%
    breaksymbol=,%
    %bgcolor=graybg,% sadly not compatible
    breakanywheresymbolpre=%
    }%
%%% REDEFINE MINTED FOR BETTER SPACING IN TABLES
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tabminted}{%
    \let\FV@ListVSpace\relax  
    \minted
}{%
    \endminted
    \unskip   
    \aftergroup\@tabmintedend
}
\newcommand*{\tabminted@finalstrut}[1]{%
    \ifdim\prevdepth>0pt
        \ifdim\dp#1>\prevdepth
            \vskip\dimexpr(\dp#1)-\prevdepth\relax
        \fi
    \else
        \vskip\dimexpr(\dp#1)\relax
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\@tabmintedend}{%
    \let\@finalstrut\tabminted@finalstrut
}
\makeatother
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}%
%
\begin{table}[h!]%
\begin{tabular} {p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}}%
\toprule%
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{Some code} & \textbf{Output}\tabularnewline%
\midrule%
some blabla & printf() & printf()\tabularnewline%   
hello world &%
\begin{tabminted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{tabminted}
& hello, world\tabularnewline%
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
%
\end{document}
```

If I do a `minipage` inside a tabular cell the top alignment gets messed up again. But here I am able to use background coloring again. Thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132793/how-to-align-tabular-to-the-top-of-the-side-by-side-minipage#132795) I can align the minipage top perfectly - although this `vspace`always feels *hacky* to me (I swapped out `heavyrulewidth` for `lightrulewidth`).
[image: minted-backgroundcolor-minipage]

```
\documentclass[%
    twoside=false,%
    paper=a4,%
    DIV=15,%)
    BCOR=0mm,%
    parskip=false,%
    fontsize=10pt,%
    ]{scrreprt}%
%%% TABLES
%\usepackage{array}%
%\usepackage{tabu}%
%\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
%%% COLORS
\usepackage{color}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{graybg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
%%% CODE HIGHLIGHTING
\usepackage[
    cache=false%
    ]{minted}
\setminted[c]{%
    autogobble=true,%
    breakanywhere=true,%
    breaklines=true,%
    breaksymbol=,%
    bgcolor=graybg,%
    breakanywheresymbolpre=%
    }%
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}%
%
\begin{table}[h!]%
\begin{tabular} {p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}}%
\toprule%
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{Some code} & \textbf{Output}\tabularnewline%
\midrule%
some blabla & printf() & printf()\tabularnewline%   
hello world &%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\lightrulewidth+\abovetopsep\relax}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
& hello, world\tabularnewline%
\bottomrule%
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
%
\end{document}
```

To get something similar like `tabulinesep` I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment#26692). `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` does the trick.
If someone wants to use minted within a `longtable`-environment `tabminted` does *not* do the trick. You need to nest `minted` in a `minipage` to get the correct alignment. I added a picture to show the differences.
[image: longtable with minted and tabminted]

```
\documentclass[%
    twoside=false,%
    paper=a4,%
    DIV=15,%)
    BCOR=0mm,%
    parskip=false,%
    fontsize=10pt,%
    ]{scrreprt}%
%%% TABLES
%\usepackage{array}%
%\usepackage{tabu}%
%\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{longtable}%
%%% COLORS
\usepackage{color}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{graybg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}%
%%% CODE HIGHLIGHTING
\usepackage[
    cache=false
    ]{minted}
\setminted[c]{%
    autogobble=true,% 
    breakanywhere=true,% 
    breaklines=true,%
    breaksymbol=,% 
    %bgcolor=graybg,% not compatible without minipage
    breakanywheresymbolpre=% 
    }%
%%% REDEFINE MINTED FOR BETTER SPACING IN TABLES
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tabminted}{%
    \let\FV@ListVSpace\relax  
    \minted
}{%
    \endminted
    \unskip   
    \aftergroup\@tabmintedend
}
\newcommand*{\tabminted@finalstrut}[1]{%
    \ifdim\prevdepth>0pt
        \ifdim\dp#1>\prevdepth
            \vskip\dimexpr(\dp#1)-\prevdepth\relax
        \fi
    \else
        \vskip\dimexpr(\dp#1)\relax
    \fi
}
\newcommand*{\@tabmintedend}{%
    \let\@finalstrut\tabminted@finalstrut
}
\makeatother
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}%
%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}}
%no caption nor label
\tabularnewline

\toprule
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{Some code} & \textbf{Output}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\textbf{Description} & \textbf{Some code} & \textbf{Output}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

tabminted in longtable-environment & 
\begin{tabminted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{tabminted}
&
line one\newline 
line two\newline
line three\newline 
line four\newline 
line five\newline 
line six\tabularnewline
minted-environment & 
\begin{minted}{c} 
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
&
line one\newline 
line two\newline
line three\newline 
line four\newline 
line five\newline 
line six\tabularnewline
minted- nested in minipage-environment & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{c} 
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted} 
\end{minipage}
&
line one\newline 
line two\newline
line three\newline 
line four\newline 
line five\newline 
line six\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
%
\end{document}
```